# Prove that there are no more than $2$ groups of order $21$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Prove that there are no more than $2$ groups of order $21$. How many elements of order $3$ are there in nonabelian group of order $21$?

I have seen few answered questions like this, but none of them help me because I am not allowed to use Sylow's theorems. This is task from exam few years ago and  I am not sure did my professor allow them at the time nor is this even possible to prove without Slyow's theorems.

Comment: You don't need Sylow's theorem for this - Cauchy's Theorem is enough. Are you allowed to use that?

Comment: @DerekHolt yes. Can you show me how? I have concluded that one of groups will be $\mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{7}$, but don't know what to do further.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750121/for-p-q-primes-such-that-qp-1-show-there-is-only-one-non-abelian-group-of/2750150#2750150).

Comment: @Dietrich Burde But that uses Sylow's theorem.

Comment: Yes, this is right. But the OP writes "I am not sure did my professor allow them (Sylow)". So it seems also useful to have a proof using Sylow. And learning Sylow seems to be useful anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a sketch proof. Let $G$ be a group of order $21$. Then by Cauchy $G$ has an element $x$ of order $7$. Let $P = \langle x \rangle$. Then $P$ is the unique subgroup of $G$ of order $7$, becuase if there was another one $Q$ then we would have $|PQ|=49>|G|$. So $P \lhd G$.

By Cauchy again, $G$ has an element $y$ of order $3$. Then the elements of $S = \{ x^iy^j : 0 \le i \le 6, 0 \le j \le 2 \}$ are all distinct, so $|S|=21$ and hence $S=G$.

Since $P \lhd G$, we have $yxy^{-1} = x^i$ for some $i$ with $1 \le i \le 6$. So $yx = x^iy$, and this relation together with $x^7=y^3=1$ enable us to multiply any two elements of $S$ together. So the isomorphism type of $G$ is determined by $i$.

These three relations also imply that $i=1,2$ or $4$ (I'll leave that as an exercise). Note that $yxy^{-1} = x^4 \Rightarrow y^{-1}xy = x^2$, so by interchanging $y$ and $y^{-1}$, we see that the groups defined by $i=2$ or $4$ (assuming that they exist at all) are isomorphic.

So there are at most two isomorphism types of groups of order $21$, which was what you had to prove. In fact, when $i=1$, we get the abelian group $C_7 \times C_3$, and when $i=2$ or $4$, we get the nonabelian group.

Answer (score 1):

Since any two non abelian group of order $pq$ (where $p,q$ are prime and $p<q,p|q-1$) are isomorphic.
Now, if $G$ is abelian then by Cauchy's theorem $G$ has normal subgroups of order $3$ and $7$ call them $H,K$.
Then, $G$ is isomorphic to $H\times K$ and again $H,K$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3,\mathbb{Z}_7$ respectively.
Hence, $G$ is isomorphic $\mathbb{Z_3}\times \mathbb{Z}_7$.
Hence,the proof is done!

Edit: look at here for a proof of first part,
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/63257/694028

Also to show that, the subgroup(say,N) of order $q$ is normal, one can use the fact that $p$ is the smallest prime that divides the order of the group, even it's an  unique subgroup of order $q$, since $(|N|,[G:N])=1$

Comment: I think your first statement requires a proof.

Comment: Proof added,check it.

Comment: The proof you linked for the first part uses Sylow's theorem, which the OP says is not allowed.

Comment: @Jonathan,look at the edited part.I mentioned there how to handle the Sylow part used in the proof.